# Wake up screen on notification recieved

Tags: java, android

So when the user receives a notification while the lockscreen is on the screen should light up.

```
private void unlockScreen() {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

I have this to unlock the screen. Then I'm using this to call it

```
private void updateNotification(int notificationCode)
{
    switch(notificationCode)
    {
        case NotificationService.InterceptedNotificationCode.FACEBOOK_CODE:
            shapeRoundButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggle_on);
            unlockScreen();
            break;
        case NotificationService.InterceptedNotificationCode.OTHER_NOTIFICATIONS_CODE:
            shapeRectangleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggle_on);
            break;
    }
}
```

The `shapeRoundButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.toggle_on)` works perfectly fine, but the unlockScreen(); doesn't. The notification is being received.

Anyone know why the screen isn't being unlocked or how I can unlock the screen? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
Log.e("screen on.................................", ""+isScreenOn);
if(isScreenOn==false)
{
    WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MyLock");
    wl.acquire(10000);
    WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyCpuLock");

    wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an IntentService. Replace your intent target with your intent service:

```
Intent yepIntent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
yepIntent.putExtra("foo", true);
yepIntent.putExtra("bar", "more info");
PendingIntent yepPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, notificationId, yepIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.icon_of_choice, "My Action", yepPendingIntent);
```

Register your service in the Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="app.great.mypackage.MyIntentService"
    android:exported="false"/>
```

Your Service could look like this:

```
public class MyIntentSerice extends IntentService {
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("myapp", "I got this awesome intent and will now do stuff in the background!");
    // .... do what you like
 }
}
```

UPDATE with feedback from Name

The trick seems to be to

1. Use a service
2. Add the intent not as an action or a contentIntent, but with the RemoteViews method.

Combined it will be:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");

 int notificationId = 1;
 Intent yepIntent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
 yepIntent.setAction("test");
 yepIntent.putExtra("foo", true);
 yepIntent.putExtra("bar", "more info");
 PendingIntent yepPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 
 notificationId, yepIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

// doesn't show up on my lock-screen
//builder.addAction(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha, "My Action", 
yepPendingIntent);

// asks for unlock code for some reason
//builder.setContentIntent(yepPendingIntent);

// Bingo
RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_closebtn_ib, yepPendingIntent);
builder.setContent(view);
```

Comment: Probably should have made it clearer but I'm not making an notification but receiving them from apps such as Facebook, Instagram and the likes. But I'll give this a go anyway and see what happens.